# mx.charts.chartClasses::ChartElement could not be found

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, flex3, data-visualization

I am encountering this problem when trying to upgrade a legacy project from `Flex SDK 3.3` to `Flex SDK 3.6`

The error gets thrown at runtime only, at compile time there is no issue.

My hunch is that it has something to do with DataVisualization components.
 
Though all datavisualization swc's are in place, I am still getting this error.

Even did a fresh download of the 3.6 SDK, overlayed the 3.6 DataVisualization swc's, still the same thing.

Using Flash Builder 4.6 Premium

Has anyone encountered this before?

Any help on this matter would be more than welcome.

Cheers

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace for the error.  Are the DatVisualization SWCs you're using compiled with the Flex 3.6 SDK?  SWCs compiled w/ different versions than your main SDK can cause a host of obscure issues.

Comment: @flextras. Yes, as stated i downloaded the official 3.6 sdk and also overlayed the official 3.6 datavisualization swc's. Unfortunately this is the full stack trace.. hence my confusion

Comment: My bad; you were explicit on version numbers there.  Sorry.  At this point my best suggestion is to post enough code to demo the problem.  Possibly a link to a project, or at least your "Customized" SDK download.

Comment: @flextras, np. You are known for giving quality answers everytime. Well almost :P Will try to post some more details as I proceed with the upgrade. Will probably be in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by using an incompatible `flexlib.swc` library.

Updating flexlib from version 1.9 to 2.5 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the  Flex SDK 3.6 that you have downloaded does not contain the charting components.

Be aware that only flex premium license allows charting framework usage without a watermark.

Check:

[Adobe Flex Charting SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919728/adobe-flex-charting-sdk)

[Flex Charting Trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768976/flex-charting-trial)

Comment: Please read my post carefully. All data visualization swc's are in place. I downloaded a clean SDK and overlayed DataVisualization swc's. I can admit though that I should have specified this more explicitely.

Comment: i think you just edited that post later. sorry did not saw the update. In that case something is strange. so all is ok if you just use sdk 3.3 ? what is the runtime error saying ?

Comment: Indeed I did edit the post to disambiguate.
However as stated, it was there from the beginning though I admit that I should have specified this more explicitely. The runtime error is saying just what is specified in the post title, there is no error stack or anything to go on. Everything is ok when using 3.3, but when switching to 3.6 we encounter this problem.

Comment: Could you please search your project for "ChartElement" and put a breakpoint in any place where it is declared / used ?  Also look for import tags, maybe you have a wrong: import mx.charts.chartClasses.ChartElement;

Comment: No occurences in my project whatsoever. However, we are using FlexLib (swc) which might be the likely culprit.

Comment: ok... then flexLib.swc is your problem. You can also get the source code for it, and assign it as a linked project. This way you can debug  the flexLib as/mxml code and detect the source of the problem. It is strange that you do not get any console details of the error like line number and so on. I presume you are using the debug and not the run button in eclipse/flexbuilder, right ?

Comment: It has something to do with exporting DataVisualization and FlexLib as RSLs. And yes, of course I am debugging :)

Comment: Shouldn't the link type be merged into code and not RSL? But if you need RSL make sure it is set to copy to deployment path.